# Probability of picking an even number from natural number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading the book A First Course In Probability and Markov Chains. It mentions a possible definition of a finitely additive 'probability' on $\mathbb{N}$.

Consider the probability measure $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mathbb{P}_a)$ whose mass density is $p_\alpha(n):=\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$, so that for any $E \subset \mathbb{N}$ one gets
$$\mathbb{P}_\alpha(E)=\sum_{n \in E}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$
Define $ \mathbb{P}(E):=\lim \sup_{\alpha\rightarrow 1^+}\mathbb{P}_\alpha(E) $. One can easily verify that $$\mathbb{P}(\mbox{{even numbers}})=\frac{1}{2}\cdots(*)$$.

I cannot prove the last equality$(*)$. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If $E=\mathbb{N}$ then$ \mathbb{P}_\alpha(E)=\sum_{n \in E}\frac{1}{n^\alpha} $ gives $\zeta(\alpha)$ not $1$ as it should.

Comment: The problem I mention in the comment above can of course be avoided provided you divide your definition by $\zeta(\alpha).$ [I didn't try to show what you say about even numbers though.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we want $\mathbb P(\mathbb N)$ to be $1$, we need to normalize the probabilities as
$$ \mathbb P_\alpha(E) = \frac{1}{\zeta(\alpha)}\sum_{n\in E}\frac1{n^\alpha} $$

If we do that, we can now calculate
$$ \mathbb P_\alpha(\mathrm{evens})
= \frac{1}{\zeta(\alpha)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(2n)^\alpha}
= \frac{1}{\zeta(\alpha)}\frac{1}{2^\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha} 
= \frac{1}{2^\alpha}\mathbb P_\alpha(\mathbb N) = \frac1{2^\alpha} $$
which clearly goes to $\frac12$ as $\alpha\to 1$.